What it takes to combine Many-worlds and Copenhagen together?
Many-worlds and Copenhagen are the two major interpretations (actually features) of quantum mechanics, and both are valid to some degree. So, instead of arguing and battling over their differences, why can’t we think of a way to bring the two together into a single mechanism. The question is, what it takes to envision a scheme that can accommodate both Many-worlds and Copenhagen?
While we are in this unifying different interpretations (or features) mode, maybe we should also throw in the Bayesian interpretation (feature) as well.
To clarify, each valid interpretation in QM actually reflects a feature in QM. That is, MWI is a distinctive feature in QM and so is Copenhagen, and that is why we say both are valid in terms of physics. People tend to use the word "interpretation" to refer to a major feature in QM and then somehow regard it as a sort of man made fantasy since it is called an interpretation. The feature referred to by a valid "interpretation" exists just as the whole QM exists.

This question is not about physics but about the interpretation of some models. Thus, it is philosophy.

There are not Many-Copenhagens though. Just the one. Well, except for Copenhagen NY on the other side of the ocean.

The focus here is to imagine the possibility of combing many-worlds and Copenhagen, but apparently, people are more interested in pulling the two apart.

It is not even close to accurate to say that these are the two primary interpretations. There are many interpretations, and more being added regularly. Bohmian Mechanics is very popular, for example. Most top scientists do not particularly agree on interpretations, and in fact, many don’t have strong opinions that don’t change.  See: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1069 an older (1997) survey by Tegmark Shows that MWI is popular, but is probably a biased survey.

Many worlds do not make sense. Not even this one.

The problem is that the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics tries to get rid of the very cern of the Copenhagen interpretation: the idea that the act of measurement results in an instantanous collapse of the wave function. The MW interpretation attempts to maintain a fully predictable, continuous time-evolution governed by the Schrodinger equation, something that the Copenhagen interpretation postulates is not possible when an observer affects the system. If one tries to refute the other, I don't believe it makes sense to try to unite them.
Furthermore, none of them offers a method to be distinguished from the other (currently, at least). Perhaps, a more fruitful path in studying interpretations of quantum mechanics would be trying to do something akin to what J. Bell did in 1960's: to find a way to objectively measure differences between these interpretations.

In your argument, you made an implicit assumption that the time running in Many-worlds and the time used in Copenhagen are the same time.
What makes you so sure that the physics of Many-worlds and the physics of Copenhagen should be running in the same type of time?

What reason would you have to think that they use different concepts of time?

Because many-worlds and Copenhagen are so different, it is natural to think they are running in different kinds to time. On the other hand, to insists that they should being running under the same instance of time makes no sense.

@southwind The MWI- and C-interpretations are just two different ways of attributing the properties of quantum mechanics to some abstract physical reality. They use the exact same formulae, laws, and time coordinates. This is the whole point of an interpretation of quantum mechanics - whatever interpretation you use, you will always agree on the outcome of quantum-mechanical experiments.

@controlgroup Each interpretation actually reflects a feature in QM. That is, MWI is a distinctive feature in QM and so is Copenhagen, and that is why we say both are valid in terms of actual physics. Just because people used the word "interpretation" to refer to a major feature in QM does not mean the feature is a man made fantasy. The feature referred to by an "interpretation exists just as the whole QM exists.

If each interpretation produced different features, they would be distinguishable. One of the key aspects of the MWI and C is that they are not distinguishable.

@southwind There is nothing in both interpretations that suggests different concepts of time. They both work in a nonrelativistic frame of quantum mechanics, where time is a simple parameter associated to evolutions in the system. While in Copenhagen this evolution has an exceptional discontinuity in the act of measurement, in MW, it does not. But time works the same on both. If you have different evidence, please attach the paper that claims such, and I can give a look into it.

@controlgroup, MCI and C are quite distinguishable in concept, but their difference in physics effect is not observable, just like phase transition or many other mysteries in QM are not observable. But we don't deny phase transition in wavefunction because it is not observable.

By "indistinguishable" I mean that there is no physically-measurable difference between the two because they are the same set of laws. The interpretation is just what meaning we ascribe to the equations; the equations are the same across all interpretations.

@LukasMontenegro, You literally said it. The time in MCI is continuous and the time in C is discontinuous. Why do you still think these two time are the same time? Also, what makes you think that time is just a parameter in QM? That is a huge disrespect to the nature and the subject of time.

@southwind, the time evolution in the two different interpretations is different- Copenhagen presenting a discontinuity upon measurement. Time itself is not different from both interpretations. And yes, in terms of quantum mechanics, time is a parameter associated to a particular type of evolution. Again, if you have any evidences to the contrary, please present your references.

@controlgroup, as I said, there are a lot of physics at work in QM that is non-observable. And again, we go back to the semantic, you call it interpretation, I call it feature. Also, the same physics law can have different features.

@LukasMontenegro, so you recognize there can be different types of evolution, but you insist time is only a dummy parameter. If so, why should QM bother with time?

I would argue that "interpretation" and "feature" generally have different meanings, and also that the same physical law (i.e. same equations, constants, etc.) by definition have the same features...

@controlgroup, we can use particle-wave duality in QM as an example. particle and wave are very different features but they represent the same underlying thing. MWI vs C can be viewed in similar way.

If that’s the nomenclature you want to use, then sure.
